# Count char in fasta (alignment) file

Tags: awk, count, char, fasta

I try to find a way to count char(n) recurrence in a fasta(alignment) file considering that this are on the start or end of the sequence. Ignoring the chars inside of the sequences.

Example:

input:

```
>chromosome1
============
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
TGTGAAGATGCTGGAGGAAACAGGTAnnCAAAAGTATCTATATCCACAGTAAAACAAGTCCTATATTGACAT
CCTGAAAGGCCTCTCAGCAAGGAAGAAGCCACTGCTCCAAAACCGCCAnnnTAAAAAAGCCAGACTACGGTT
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn.
```

output

```
71
74
```

At this moment I can count how many chars(n) are in the whole sequence with

```
awk '{print gsub (srch,srch)}' srch="n"
```

but I need an idea (code) to distinguish the two groups before and after the large block.

Comment: [edit] your question to include the expected output given your posted sample input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the first line after the `>header` and the last line before the next `>header` or end of file, try something like

```
awk '/^>/ { if (FNR>1) print n; n=0; p=1; next }
{ n=gsub("n", "n") }
p { print n; p=0 }
END { print n }' file.fasta
```

(I have assumed the `============` line is not actually part of your data.)

Answer (score 0):

With just awk you can use the following script. It counts the length of all sequences of `srch` and prints at the end the length of the first and last sequence found:

```
# count.awk
BEGIN {
    FS=""
    n=0 
}

NR > 2 { 
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        # Increment current group if current character equals srch
        if($i == srch) {
            grp[n]++
        } else {
            # Next group
            n++
            # Next character
            i++
            # Iterate trough line until next sequence of srch
            while($i != srch && i <= NF) {
                i++
                # The next sequence starts
                if ($i == srch) {
                    grp[n]++
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
END {
    print "Begin: ", grp[0]
    print "End: ", grp[n-1]
}
```

call it like this:

```
awk -v srch=n -f count.awk input.fasta
```

Comment: thanks hek2mgl, but I don´t want the result for the whole number of n in the file. I need to separate the n that comes on the start from them that are on the end. Also ignoring that, that are inside of the block.

Comment: @Babi Are the first `n` always in the first line and the last `n` always in the last line?

Comment: No. Just in this example it is the case. In other files I have different number of n and can be more than one line long. I also considered to transform the file in one line and insert a break after n, but this will be include that small results inside of the block also.

Answer (score 0):

I find this question rather vague, but this `awk` script might help:

```
/^n+\.$/ { print "after: " length($0) - 1; next; }
/^n+$/   { print "before: " length($0) }
```